# Multiple threads running in iOS when only one thread should be run from within method

Tags: maui

I'd post this on github, but it appears that there isn't a project page or discussion set up for it.

I'm working with the MauiSpeechToText example located here: https://github.com/jfversluis/MauiSpeechToTextSample  by @gerald.verslu.is  (Great example BTW - thank you)

I connected the project to my Mac which my iPAD is connected to it.  The example compiles and runs fine.

However, in going through some of the inner workings of the app, I discovered that when I touched the "listen" button that it would spin up 3 or 4 speechRecognizer.GetRecognitionTask tasks.  None of the code above that line (line 59 / task Listen(...) ) is run multiple times even though the method itself is only run once. And there's no loop iteration going on.

I created my own app based off this code and saw the same thing happen.  I went back to the original example code and test it and found that the same thing was occurring.

This is the code in question as referenced in the SpeechToTextImplementation.cs located in the Platforms\iOS folder:

```
    var currentIndex = 0;
    var taskResult = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();
    Debug.Writeline("Starting recognition task");
    // the code above here is only run once when I set a break point to watch the process or set up Debug.Writeline() to report while it's being run
    // **** next line is line 59 which appears to be the running the code inside of this multiple times
    recognitionTask = speechRecognizer.GetRecognitionTask(liveSpeechRequest, (result, err) =>
    {
        if (err != null)
        {
            StopRecording();
            taskResult.TrySetException(new Exception(err.LocalizedDescription));
        }
        else
        {
            if (result.Final)  // <--- this is line 68
            {
                currentIndex = 0;
                StopRecording();
                taskResult.TrySetResult(result.BestTranscription.FormattedString);
            }
            else
            {
                for (var i = currentIndex; i < result.BestTranscription.Segments.Length; i++)
                {
                    var s = result.BestTranscription.Segments[i].Substring;
                    currentIndex++;
                    recognitionResult?.Report(s);
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

I set a breakpoint on line 68 and ran a debug on the ipad.  I can see additional threads spinning up in the debug window.  I originally thought it was just the GetRecognitionTask task/event responding multiple times, but it actually appears to be multiple threads responding in sequence with the same thing.  I also set up a Debug.Writeline to show more information as this process is running.

The main issue comes into play when you want to shut down the task and re-open it.  I've found workarounds but it's not clean, it involves a lot of error handling when the thread objects are dereferenced by one thread, then the other threads are referencing nulled objects.

I can continue going down the path of using error handling to keep this running, I'm just concerned that it's not cleaning the resources up correctly\cleanly.

Is this something that is occurring from the Speech API?

Comment: I can't make sure what cause it. But the [Progress<T>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.progress-1?view=net-7.0#remarks) mentioned the threadpool and the [async / await](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/how-async-await-really-works/) also work with the thread pool sometime.

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT whatever is causing it is preventing the class from ending cleanly. The way Apple deals with this is a max of 1 minute of voice recognition at a time. So to get around that, I need to open, end when phrase is done, and re-open for next request.  Is there a place I can report this for MS engineers to look at it?

Comment: You can check this thread about the [1 minute limit for the ecognition](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/131940).